# Controlling gpio from serial port rpi

Tags: python, automation, pyserial, gpio

I have 2 pis connected via serial, this works no problem, now this is just an idea at the moment but I want to have 8 switches on RPi1 control 8 outputs on RPi2 only communicating via serial wire and preferably in Python.

Outputs should be as live as possible, I've tried googling this but everything I come up with is just about the GPIO UART pins...

Can someone point me I the right direction for learning this, basically I thought that sending 0b00000001 should activate output 1 and sending 0b10000001 would activate outputs 1 and 8 and so on, looking for pointers on how to build the data packet from the inputs and put them on the wire

If this works, I've also got an idea to do the same in reverse, is this possible with serial?

Comment: You might have better luck at [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: So, what the problem? On one side you use `python-serial` on the other `libgpiod` (it has Python bindings).

Comment: As it is, each character could encode the entire state.  No packet necessary, just one character every time you want to change the output.

Comment: So, show your python code you wrote.